# How to formulate equality predicate on POINT column in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, operator, geometry

How to select from a table with an equality predicate on `point` column?
To be clear: it's a native Postgres `point` data type, not `geometry(point)` from PostGIS.

```
select a.* from indsolv.address As a where a.location = '93.2321, 21.0321';
```

Getting this error for the above query:

> ```
> ERROR:  operator does not exist: point = unknown
> LINE 1: ...ct a.* from indsolv.address As a where a.location = '93.2321...
>                                                          ^
> HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
> SQL state: 42883
> ```

Also tried:

```
select a.* from indsolv.address As a where a.location = point('93.2321,21.0321');
```

Still getting an error.

Comment: Do not cross-post: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/339988/how-to-select-from-point-column-in-postgresql

Comment: Please clarify (and then decide on which board you want to post) if this is about the native PostgreSQL `POINT` type, or the PostGIS `GEOMETRY(POINT)` type!

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add the complete `create table` statement for the table in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try as it might, [operator type resolution](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/typeconv-oper.html) will find no appropriate operator and give up with the error message you reported.

> ```
> ERROR:  operator does not exist: point = unknown
> ```

Adding an explicit type cast (or the `point()` function achieving the same) to the right argument like you did in your added second attempt will only succeed in making the error message a bit more revealing:

> ```
> ERROR:  operator does not exist: point = point
> ```

The subtle difference may serve as hint: the problem is *not* a missing cast (though being explicit about data types is never a bad idea). The problem is that there is, in fact, **no equality operator `=`** defined for the data type `point`. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-geometry.html)

> Note that the “same as” operator, **`~=`**, represents the usual notion of
>   equality for the `point`, `box`, `polygon`, and `circle` types. Some of these types
>   also have an `=` operator, but `=` compares for equal areas only. The other scalar
>   comparison operators (`<=` and so on) likewise compare areas for these types.

For the data type `point`, there is **no `=` at all**. See for yourself (tested in Postgres 12):

```
SELECT *            -- no rows
FROM   pg_operator
WHERE  oprleft = 'point'::regtype
AND    oprname = '=';
```

The **solution** is to use the appropriate [**"same as" operator `~=`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-geometry.html#FUNCTIONS-GEOMETRY-OP-TABLE) instead. Works with or without explicit type cast, [with or without enclosing parentheses in the string literal](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-geometric.html#id-1.5.7.16.5), and with the function notation you tested as well - and in this case with either type of string literal as well as with two separate parameters as there are multiple overloaded versions of the `point()` function:

```
SELECT a.* FROM indsolv.address a
WHERE a.location ~= point '(93.2321, 21.0321)';

... WHERE a.location ~= point '93.2321, 21.0321';
... WHERE a.location ~= '93.2321, 21.0321'::point;
... WHERE a.location ~= '(93.2321, 21.0321)'::point;
... WHERE a.location ~= cast('93.2321, 21.0321' AS point);
... WHERE a.location ~= cast('(93.2321, 21.0321)' AS point);

... WHERE a.location ~= '(93.2321, 21.0321)';
... WHERE a.location ~= '93.2321, 21.0321';

... WHERE a.location ~= point('93.2321, 21.0321)';
... WHERE a.location ~= point('(93.2321, 21.0321)');
... WHERE a.location ~= point('93.2321', '21.0321');
```

Related:

- [ERROR:could not identify an equality operator for type point](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44005459/939860)
- [Creating custom “equality operator” for PostgreSQL type (point) for DISTINCT calls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34971757/939860)